# TinyMce: Insert hyperlink and continue writing extends link

Tags: html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a TinyMce (version 4) configured with the following settings:

```
forced_root_block: false
force_br_newlines: true
```

If the user adds a hyperlink (via the link dialog) and continues writing, the following text extends the link: It is rendered as a link and clickable, targeting to the url of the previously added link.

I think the desired behaviour would be to write "normal" text after inserting the link. I can solve this by using e.g. `<p>` as a `forced_root_block` but this is not what I want. Are there any other ways to deal with this?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I'm using <p> as forced_root_block again. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `<p>` as `forced_root_block` because I could not find another proper solution for this problem.

I'd also like to quote this warning from the [documentation](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block) here:

> Note that not using P elements as root block can severly cripple the
>   functionality of the editor.